# Returning value in C programming

Tags: c

I have the following problem, where X=10, Y=85 and D=30 are already defined.

```
int solution (int X, int Y, int D) 
{     
        //put your code here 
}
```

I need to count the number till the value of X reaches to Y, when X is added to D, for example X = X+D

I know the return value must be 3, this is what I have done,

```
    int count = 0;
    int solution (int X, int Y, int D)
    {
       if (X<=Y)
       {
          count++;
          X = X+D;
       }
       else
      {
        return count;
      }
    }
```

But I am just a return value as 0, where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You forgot the cycle?

Comment: the if statement doesn't return anything

Comment: Since, it is not going in else part, it is returning the default return value 0. But it must have given you the error/warning that "not all control paths return value"?

Answer (score 3):

You should use division to solve this problem:

```
if (X > Y)
  return 0;

int count = (Y - X) / D + 1;   
return count;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `if .. else` to do it. Because it will executed only one time. When the execution of function finished it won't return anything, `if` does not have `return` statement!

You should use loop's to do-

```
int count = 0;
int solution (int X, int Y, int D)
{
   while(X<=Y) // executes till the condition fails
   {
      count++;
      X = X+D;
   }
}
```

In this case you are having `count` as a global variable. So no need to return it. but if you have it as a local one you should return it-

```
int solution (int X, int Y, int D)
{
   int count = 0;
   while(X<=Y) // executes till the condition fails
   {
      count++;
      X = X+D;
   }
   return count;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of returning the count variable if you have it as global variable?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly and if the numbers will be non-negative.

**Solution:**

```
    int solution (int X, int Y, int D)
    {
       int count = 0;

       while (X < Y)
       {
          count++;
          X += D;
       }

        return count;
    }
```

The `count` really doesn't have to be global, since your method will return it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int solution (int X, int Y, int D){
    int count;
    for(count = 0; X <= Y; X += D)
        ++count;
    return count;
}
```